# Perforce: How to Integrate Upto a Certain Changelist From One Branch to Other

Tags: integration, perforce

I am trying to take all our recent code from our development branch to release branch upto a certain changelist (say CL no. 1234). How can I achieve that?

I know that I can do `p4 describe 1234` to see the timestamp and then do `p4 integ //path/to/dev/branch/...@timestamp //path/to/release/branch/...`. But is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: `p4 integ //path/to/dev/branch/...@1234 //path/to/release/branch/...`?

Comment: @devnull Will this not integrate only the CL 1234?

Comment: @NilanjanBasu No, it will integrate *everything* up until CLN 1234.  Integrating a single change requires using the revision *range* syntax, e.g. `//path/to/dev/branch/...@1234,1234`.  You can run `p4 help revisions` for more information about the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrate your dev branch (source) into your release branch (target) at a changelist, rather than integrating using a timestamp.  Since you want to integrate up through CL 1234, you should run the following command:

```
p4 integrate //path/to/dev/branch/...@1234 //path/to/release/branch/...
```

This integrates the dev branch (all files in the state they were in after CL 1234 was submitted) into the release branch.